# MvvmCross: What is the purpose of the enum MvxRequestedByType?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross

Looking at the MvvmCross source code I see this [enum](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8a824c797747f74716fc64c2fd0e8765c29b16ab/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxRequestedByType.cs), which appears to be used only in `MvxRequestedBy`. My question is what is that enum there for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It is not used for anything currently. They are always set to `MvxRequestedBy.Unknown`. I don't know the original intention. However, it could be that you could use that in the presenter to design different flows in the app depending of the origin of the request.